# Solution to a slow headless browser rendering html, javascript to a screenshot image in python?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome-headless

I've built an API with flask that uses the [chrome headless](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) driver and [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) in python to render a given address containing a simple html page with some javascript and take a snapshot of the rendered page.
After deploying to the server the requests take too long because the headless browser has to execute with every request which is slow.

Is there a faster approach to using the headless browser or a replacement that can get the requested html, javascript and render it like a browser in python to obtain a screenshot?

```
def create_screenshot(id):

options = Options()

options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # Last I checked this was necessary.
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1920")

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', chrome_options=options,
                        service_args=['--verbose', '--log-path=/tmp/chromedriver.log'])
driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:1234/snippet/{0}".format(id))

driver.maximize_window()

element = driver.find_element_by_id("snapArea")
location = element.location
size = element.size
x = location['x']
y = location['y']
width = location['x']+size['width']
height = location['y']+size['height']
png = driver.get_screenshot_as_png()

im = Image.open(BytesIO(png))
im = im.crop((int(x), int(y), int(width), int(height)))

path = create_folder(id)
im.save(path)
return path
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of initializing the driver every time, why not create it at start in a class (ie, as a property called "self.driver") and then call it whenever you need it?
Something like this:

```
class DriverContainer:
    def __init__(self):
        options = Options()

        options.add_argument('--headless')
        options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
        options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1920")

        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', chrome_options=options,
                        service_args=['--verbose', '--log-path=/tmp/chromedriver.log'])

    def take_screenshot(self, id):
        self.driver.get("http://127.0.0.1:1234/snippet/{0}".format(id))

        self.driver.maximize_window()
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_id("snapArea")
        location = element.location
        size = element.size
        x = location['x']
        y = location['y']
        width = location['x']+size['width']
        height = location['y']+size['height']
        png = self.driver.get_screenshot_as_png()

        im = Image.open(BytesIO(png))
        im = im.crop((int(x), int(y), int(width), int(height)))

        path = create_folder(id)
        im.save(path)
```

Then you instantiate it with `driver_container = DriverContainer()` and just do `driver_container.take_screenshot(id)` when needed. This way the browser will skip as the slow startup, which is in my experience what's slowest about selenium.

Comment: what would happen if more than one request is make to take a screenshot?

Comment: @Farzan the class would execute them in the order they are received.